# Name for %@ %d in an NSString

Tags: objective-c, string, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsstring

What are these called in Objective C? `@"%@"` `@"%d"` `@"%i"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are called format specifiers, could also be called 'placeholders in a string for the variables that will follow'.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Answer (score 2):

They are `NSString literal`s.  More specifically, they look they are being used as **formatting strings** for `printf` style functions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that they are called 'format placeholders', as suggested by this wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Format_placeholders

Comment: It seems they are called 'format specifiers' by Apple as pointed out by 0x8badf00d, but I suspect that they have many names as they are very common in many languages.